# Android get nearby tweets using twitter API

Tags: android, twitter, geolocation

I am developing android application, I am looking for a solution on getting the near by tweets based on my current location for example I need to get tweets near me within 6 km radius. I tried many API's I m still unable to find it. Please let me know if anyone has implemented the same example. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The Twitter API docs demonstrate how to do this perfectly. See here https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/filtering-tweets-by-location.html

Comment: Hi is there any example android application for this, I tried all possible ways and I am still not getting to fetch this API

Comment: I tried getting OAuth first and then I tried fetching places using resource URL provided in the documentation.